# Azure AD: Best Practices on session timeout / token invalidation

Tags: session, azure-active-directory, timeout, single-sign-on

We are working together with a software provider that provides a password manager solution, based on a classic client-server architecture. The users authenticate via the client through Azure AD in order to access the server.

We do have a corporate security requirement that any idle session (5 minutes) shall be force closed, which also applies to said application.

However, given that we receive the session token from Azure AD, the timeout settings from AAD apply (1 hour or more), which violates the requirement. Speaking to the vendor, he says that they should not control the session timeout via the client. Relaying on the AAD setting would be SSO best practice and this is how all other OAuth2/OIDC clients work. Instead, they refer to the AAD to decrease the token's life time.

As I am not an expert in this field, could you please comment on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, you can reduce the Azure AD token lifetime, and it can be a solution to your scenario.

As the session timeout is set to 5 minutes, you can use the below PowerShell script to reduce the token lifetime.

For **sample**, I reduced the token lifetime to 10 minutes.

```
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId TenantID -Scopes "Policy.ReadWrite.TrustFramework"

$params = @{  
Definition = @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:10:00"}}')  
DisplayName = "WebPolicyScenario"  
IsOrganizationDefault = $true  
}  
$tokenLifetimePolicyId=(New-MgPolicyTokenLifetimePolicy -BodyParameter $params).Id
```

[image]

Now, when I generated the **access token** using below Parameters the token lifetime is set to 10 minutes like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

- Reducing the token lifetime might cause the user experience bad where the user needs to re-authenticate frequently.
- You can make use of refresh token to refresh the access token.
- Default token lifetime value of refresh token is 90 days.
- Default token lifetime value of session token is until revoked.
- **Hence**, reducing the token lifetime policy can be the solution if the user experience is handled.